# Multiple Sql Counts

Tags: sql, count

I have a table (tbl_MatterItem) in my DB that tracks the dates that items are sent and received.  If it hasn't been sent or received, the value is NULL.  I have another table (tbl_Matter) that I am linking to, to get the BillingLawyer for that particular item.

```
BillingLawyer     ItemSent     ItemReceived
-------------     --------     ------------
   Alison         09/09/09        NULL
   Alison         10/10/10        NULL
   Alison         11/11/11       13/11/11
   Alison         12/12/12        NULL
```

I would like to retrieve one row for each lawyer with their name, the number of items sent, and the number of items received.

```
BillingLawyer    Sent    Received
-------------    -----   --------
   Alison         4         1
```

Below is what I have so far:

```
SELECT BillingLawyer, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT itemSent)FROM tbl_matteritem mit WHERE itemid=2 AND itemSent IS NOT NULL AND mit.ItemSent= mi.itemSent) AS [Sent], 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT itemReceived)FROM tbl_matteritem mitm WHERE itemid=2 AND itemReceived IS NOT NULL AND mitm.itemreceived = mi.itemreceived)AS Received
FROM tbl_matteritem mi JOIN tbl_matter m ON mi.matterid = m.matterid
GROUP BY BillingLawyer, ItemSent, itemreceived
ORDER BY 1
```

However my results show with an extra record and what appears to be bit values?:

```
BillingLawyer    Sent    Received
-------------    ----    --------
   Alison         0         0
   Alison         1         1
   Alison         1         0
   Alison         1         0
   Alison         1         0
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    BillingLawyer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ItemSent IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sent,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ItemReceived IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Received
FROM
    tbl_matteritem mi
JOIN tbl_matter m ON
    mi.matterid = m.matterid
GROUP BY BillingLawyer
ORDER BY BillingLawyer
```

Comment: +1 Best solution imho.  You could omit `else 0`: without `else`, an unmatched `case` returns `null`

Comment: Thanks. I usually leave in the zero just to be overly obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

You're grouping on `ItemSent`, so `count(distinct ItemSent`) will return either 1 or 0.  After all, a new group will be created for each different value of `ItemSent`, and the `count()` will then be applied to that group.

If you want to count items per `BillingLawyer`, group on `BillingLawyer` but not `ItemSent`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `DISTINCT` first I think because it will count for each date.

```
SELECT BillingLawyer, 
(SELECT COUNT( itemSent)FROM tbl_matteritem mit WHERE itemid=2 AND itemSent IS      NOT NULL AND mit.ItemSent= mi.itemSent) AS [Sent], 
(SELECT COUNT( itemReceived)FROM tbl_matteritem mitm WHERE itemid=2 AND itemReceived IS NOT NULL AND mitm.itemreceived = mi.itemreceived)AS Received
FROM tbl_matteritem mi JOIN tbl_matter m ON mi.matterid = m.matterid
GROUP BY BillingLawyer, ItemSent, itemreceived
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not include `ItemSent, itemreceived` in `GROUP BY`.
Use only `GROUP BY BillingLawyer`